# Perl variable doesn't stay set, even when set with "our"

Tags: arrays, perl, loops, variables, global

I have a file that I wish to search for strings, matching with items stored in an array.  I open the file, loop through it and when I find what I'm looking for, I change a variable flag so additional work can be done.  I am having an issue where the variable I set is not sticking.  I placed the variable within the foreach loop, made it an `our` variable, to no avail.

Questionable code:

```perl
my $zed = 0;
foreach my $SUB (@sub) {
    print "We are currently looking for $SUB<br><br>";

    open (my $input, "<", "C:\\Users\\scottbro\\Desktop\\PMS.txt")
        or die "Cannot open PMS.txt: $!";

    our $flag = 0;
    ##SET Zed to keep track of where we are
    print "Zed is $zed<br>Flag is $flag<br>";
    $zed++;

    while (<$input>) {

        print "inside the while loop, flag is now $flag<br>";
        ##  IF you find what you are looking for, set flag to 1
        if (/$SUB/) {
            $flag = 1;
            print "Found sub property, flag is now $flag<br>";
            ## IF flag is 1, and line has email address, show it!
        } elsif ($flag = 1 && /<email>(.+)/) {
            print "Flag is $flag, email is $1<br>";
        }

    }
    close($input);
}
```

Output, where it can be seen the flag variable loses value:

```
We are currently looking for Property 1
Zed is 0
Flag is 0
inside the while loop, flag is now 0
inside the while loop, flag is now 
Flag is 1, email is email1
inside the while loop, flag is now 1
Flag is 1, email is email2
inside the while loop, flag is now 1
inside the while loop, flag is now 
inside the while loop, flag is now 
inside the while loop, flag is now 
Found sub property, flag is now 1
inside the while loop, flag is now 1
Flag is 1, email is email3
inside the while loop, flag is now 1
Flag is 1, email is email4
inside the while loop, flag is now 1
inside the while loop, flag is now 
inside the while loop, flag is now 
Flag is 1, email is email 5
```

Comment: Also, why are you re-reading the input multiple times? That's pretty nasty.

Comment: @Sobrique, totally agreed, didn't know you could rewind.

Comment: You probably don't even need to do that. You can turn your `/SUB/` search into something like: `my $search = join ( "|", map { quotemeta } @sub ); $search = qr/($search)/;`. Because then you can do `while ( <$file> ) { if ( m/$search/ ) { print $1 } }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are *assigning* to `$flag` in your test

```
elsif  (  $flag=1 && /<email>(.+)/ ) {  ... }
```

is setting `$flag` to `1 && /<email>(.+)/` which is *false* if the regex pattern doesn't match

It should probably be

```
if  (  $flag and /<email>(.+)/ ) { ... }
```

---

I suggest you forget about `$flag` and instead use the fact that the input file will be at eof if `$sub` hasn't been found, so the program won't be able to read anything further anyway

It's also nicer to rewind the file rather than reopen it. It's almost certain that the data should be parsed into a hash and accessed directly, but I can't tell for sure with the little information you give

```
my @sub;

open my $fh, '<', 'C:\Users\scottbro\Desktop\PMS.txt' or die "Cannot open PMS.txt: $!";

for my $sub ( @sub ) {

    seek $fh, 0, 0;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        last if /$sub/;
    }

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        next unless /<email>(.+)/;
        print qq{Email for "$sub" is "$1"};
        last;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the usual `strict` and `warnings` don't pick up when you do it like that.

Comment: @Sobrique: It doesn't warn you unless you write something that is always true or false, like `if ( $f = 1 ) { ... }`. What the OP has is equivalent to  `if ( $f = /pattern/ ) { ... }` which is a legitimate test of a pattern while storing the result for reuse

Comment: `//` returns `dualvar(0,'')` on failure, not `undef` (which would have caused the OP to get "uninitialized" warnings).

Comment: @Borodin, I will take a look at what you propose, thank you.  Rewinding the file and parsing into a hash makes plenty of sense, my perl is rusty to say the least...

Comment: @Borodin, your answer made me think about assigning the value of flag when i wanted to evaluate it.  Changing = to == fixed much that wasn't making sense.  I still want to incorporate the rewind and parsing a hash, but you did get me over the hurdle i was having with my current code.  Thanks!

Comment: @Scotty: The solution I showed you doesn't need a flag, and incorporates a rewind (`seek $fh, 0, 0;`)

Answer (score -2):

You are assigning to `$flag` in your test rather than checking its value.

```
elsif ($flag = 1 && /<email>(.+)/)
```

should be

```
elsif ($flag == 1 && /<email>(.+)/)
```

Or even better,

```
elsif ($flag && /<email>(.+)/)
```

---

That said, repeatedly reading the same file is quite inefficient. Here's a version that doesn't.

```
my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @subs;

my $qfn = 'C:\\Users\\scottbro\\Desktop\\PMS.txt';
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
   or die(qq{"Can't open "$qfn": $!\n"});

while (<$fh>) {
   my ($sub) = /($pat)/
      or next;

   defined( $_ = <$fh> )
      or last;

   my ($email) = /<email>(.+)/
      or redo;

   print(qq{Email for "$sub" is "$email"\n});
}
```